# How can i read post data from table in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net

I have table name called Compnay and it has 10 cloumns. How can i read values inside each columns has user put it by user inferface (UI).

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  You're posting data from an HTML table somehow?  Or to a database table?  Please elaborate.

Comment: I have created html table. where uer can select date for each columns and i want to read that date from view to controller.

Comment: Take a peek into Request.Form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to Bind your class Name where property are with View page.

> <%@ Control Language="C#"
>   Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<**>"
>   %>

When user click on Save Button page post to controller. There you need to read data in controller

Inside Controller

> [HttpPost] Public ActionResult
>   Save(** Variable) {
>
> }

** Your Class Name where Property are.

I am not as good as other to explain this. But it's work fine.